# Disabling an implicit layer during development

Tags: c++, windows, vulkan

My development machine has Steam installed on it, which installed `SteamOverlayVulkanLayer64` as an implicit layer.

This is all fine and dandy, but it seems a recent update made a change that made it incompatible with LunarG's `VKLayer_unique_objects`. (at least as far as swap chain creation goes on windows).

Is there a sane way to disable just that one implicit layer without making a system-wide change on my machine?

For reference, I'm using the 1.1.77.0 SDK in case that's relevant in any way.

**Edit:**
On the off-chance that someone else runs into this and lands here, the steam overlay can be controlled with an environment variable:

```
if (!validation_layers.empty()) {
#ifdef WIN32
  // Steam's overlay is incompatible with LunarG's
  SetEnvironmentVariable("DISABLE_VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay_1", "1");
#endif
  [...]
}
```

However, I'd still be interested in knowing wether or not there is a way to control implicit layers in general.

Comment: You can disable just that one layer in the registry, but that's a system-wide change.

Comment: Implicit layers are intended to be "system-wide", so this approach is appropriate, even though you are debugging a single app.   Another approach would be to disable the unique objects layer, but keep the other validation layers active.  See this [information](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.77.0/windows/validation_layers.html) to see how to enable just the other validation layers.  Doing this instead of disabling the implicit layer affects only the application under test.

Comment: There's currently no way to disable all implicit layers (might be nice though to implement in loader). Steam should declare `Enable` variable in the first place, and so be off by default; it is IMO Steam's bug.

Comment: @krOoze, well, disabling all implicit layers would be a non-starter as well because RenderDoc relies on one as well so some granularity would be needed.

Comment: I thought that was your edited Q. Just saying it could be useful option for debugging though. ;; Generally all implicit layers have a safe-word, as you already found out. And the can (optionally) have enable-keyword, which makes them off by default. So what else do you mean by "way to control implicit layers in general"?

Comment: I don't think it can be made per application basis, it's system-wide. You could try `vkconfig` as it's GUI tool. There is always an option called "Undo changes on exit" enabled by default in every run thus use case might be open `vkconfig` then disable a target implicit layer as needed, then leave it running while you do per-application stuff basis. Upon exit `vkconfig`, things will return to normal. More info regarding `vkconfig` and where its configuration file is can be found [here](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.135.0/mac/vkconfig.html).

Comment: @haxpor, yes, I've been using vkconfig to handle this fairly comfortably for a while now. It simply wasn't a thing when I originally asked the question.

Comment: You can disable all implicit layers using the environment variable `VK_LOADER_LAYERS_DISABLE=~implicit~`. You can also specify wildcards like `*OBS*` to disable all OBS related layers for example. More info can be found in the [vulkan loader documentation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/main/docs/LoaderInterfaceArchitecture.md#filter-environment-variable-behaviors).
This feature was only just added in 1.3.236.0