# Disabling implicit Vulkan Validation Layer via environment variable

Tags: vulkan

Vulkan Layer API [specs describe](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.236.0/linux/LoaderLayerInterface.html) a mechanism to control activation of implicit layers via command line.

Specifically,`enable_environment` and `disable_environment` fields can be defined in the JSON manifest file as follows:

```
 {
   "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
   "layer" : {
     "name": "VK_LAYER_SAMPLE_SampleLayer",
     "type": "GLOBAL",
     "library_path": ".\\sample_layer.dll",
     "api_version": "1.0.0",
     "implementation_version": "1",
     "description": "Sample layer - https://renderdoc.org/vulkan-layer-guide.html",
     "functions": {
        "vkGetInstanceProcAddr": "SampleLayer_GetInstanceProcAddr",
        "vkGetDeviceProcAddr": "SampleLayer_GetDeviceProcAddr"
     },
     "enable_environment": {
        "ENABLE_SAMPLE_LAYER": "1"
     },
     "disable_environment": {
       "DISABLE_SAMPLE_LAYER": "1"
     }
   }
}
```

The above manifest is taken from the RenderDoc [documentation](https://renderdoc.org/vulkan-layer-guide.html).I also used the code of the sample layer discussed in that article to create my own.

After building the dll here are the steps I did to active the layer:
Opened environment variables window (I am on windows 11) and added to the system vars:

1. `VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS` = `VK_LAYER_SAMPLE_SampleLayer`
2. `VK_LAYER_PATH` = `C:\Users\defaultUser\Documents\CustomLayers`
3. `ENABLE_SAMPLE_LAYER` = 1

The above activates the layer.
Then I tried to remove the `ENABLE_SAMPLE_LAYER` and adding `DISABLE_SAMPLE_LAYER = 1` instead.
But the loader still keeps loading the layer.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572985/disabling-an-implicit-layer-during-development) question where the user tried to do the same but via code,so it should work. What am I missing here?